# TestBed configuration expecting all the components and services in the app to be injected or imported

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

my component has a constructor that takes a back-end service

```
    something = "abc";
constructor(private inspectionService: InspectionService) {//
    this.inspectionService.getMaintenanceOptions().subscribe(maintenanceOptions => {
        this.maintenanceOptions = maintenanceOptions;
    });
```

trying to setup test for this i have the following code.

```
describe('PI Time Control Comment', () => {
let mockInspectionService = jasmine.createSpyObj('InspectionService', ['getInspectionList']);
let component: InspectionFindingComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<InspectionFindingComponent>;
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
        imports: [FormsModule,AppRoutingModule, CookieModule.forRoot(), DropDownsModule,
            HttpModule, HttpClientModule, StoreModule.provideStore({ orders })],
        declarations: [InspectionFindingComponent,LoginComponent,HomeComponent,DashboardComponent], // it is expecting all the components to be injected
        providers: [CookieService, AuthenticationService, // it is requiring all the services to be injected 
            HttpHelperService, UserService, {
                provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
                useClass: AuthInterceptorService,
                multi: true
            }, {
                provide: InspectionService,
                useValue: mockInspectionService
            }]

    }).compileComponents();;
});
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(InspectionFindingComponent);
     component = fixture.componentInstance;
     fixture.detectChanges();
    // component.PO = new PurchaseOrder();
  });
it('somethinggggggggg++++++++++++++++++', () => {
    // local arrange

    // act

    // assert
    expect(component.something).toBe("abc");
});
```

when i add one component it asks for another one. and keeps on giving me errors.

"Error: Component BinningListComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module."

if i will fix this it will ask for another component. So how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can always suppress the error by creating a fake @NgModule().

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [...],
  declarations: [BinningListComponent, ... all the other component],
  exports: [BinningListComponent, ... all the other components],
})
export class TestModule {}
```

And then importing the module in your TestBed.

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        schemas: [...],
        imports: [TestModule],
        declarations: [...],
        providers: [...]
    }).compileComponents();
```

Comment: where should i be creating this fake ngModule?

Comment: it does not matter. You can create a separate file test.module.ts, and import it in the spec file. If it solved your problem, please consider accepting this answer :)